# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python

while declaring a variable with string in python i'm getting the below error

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

```
data_path ='C:\Users\amjin\My_datasets\simple-examples\data'
```

Answer (score 0):

try to write your path on this way :

```
data_path ='C:/Users/amjin/My_datasets/simple-examples/data'
```

**You can change \ with /**

or:

In Python 3, you can avoid this by using a **raw string**:

```
data_path =r'C:\Users\amjin\My_datasets\simple-examples\data'
```

The backslash ( \ ) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

example:

in your path: 'C:\Users\amjin\My_datasets\simple-examples\data'

'\a'    : ASCII bell makes ringing the bell alert sounds
print ("\a")  , result :N/A